# Find the range of values of $d$ for which the cubic equation $x^3-8x^2+12x+d=0$ has exactly $3$ distinct real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$$x^3-8x^2+12x+d=0 $$

I have worked this using calculus by finding the stationary points. However this is part of a problem which was under number theory. So I am still trying for a solution using elementary algebra / number theory or any other clever method that doesn't use calculus... Any help/suggestions ? thanks!

Comment: Take a look at (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots). You can find the values of $d$ such that $\Delta > 0$.

Comment: I think I'll get a quadratic in $d$ after plugging values in $\Delta \gt 0$ and solving $d$ looks smooth afterwards... I am going to try this right away. Thank you so much :)

Comment: For what values of $d$ would there be only 2 solutions? Try to find $a$ and $b$ such that $(x-a)^2(x-b)=x^3-8x^2+12x+d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

In order the equation has three distincts roots, the function must have a maximum and a minimum. Solving for zero the derivative shows that it cancels for $$x_{\pm}=\frac{2}{3} \left(4\pm\sqrt{7}\right)$$ But, you need also that  for the smallest root the function be strictly positive and for the largest root the function must be strictly negative.

Computing $$f\Big(\frac{2}{3} \left(4-\sqrt{7}\right)\Big)=d+\frac{16}{27} \left(7 \sqrt{7}-10\right)$$ $$f\Big(\frac{2}{3} \left(4+\sqrt{7}\right)\Big)=d-\frac{16}{27} \left(10+7 \sqrt{7}\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.